# error in converting xts to data.table

Tags: r, data.table, xts

```
library(data.table)
library(xts)

x <- xts(c(1:2,4:7,9:11), c(Sys.Date()+1:2,Sys.Date()+4:7,Sys.Date()+9:11))

as.data.table.xts(x)
Error: could not find function "as.data.table.xts"
```

But, the conversion from data.table to xts works:

```
y <- data.table(c(Sys.Date()+1:2,Sys.Date()+4:7,Sys.Date()+9:11),c(1:2,4:7,9:11))
as.xts.data.table(y)
           V2
2016-07-21  1
2016-07-22  2
2016-07-24  4
2016-07-25  5
2016-07-26  6
2016-07-27  7
2016-07-29  9
2016-07-30 10
2016-07-31 11

packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.9.7’
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling a method directly, which you generally should not do. `as.data.table.xts` is not exported from the `data.table` namespace, but it is registered as an S3 method. That means calling `as.data.table` on an xts object will dispatch to `as.data.table.xts`.

```
identical(as.data.table(x), data.table:::as.data.table.xts(x))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `as.data.table`.  In `data.table`, rownames are not allowed, so it creates an 'index' column as the first column

```
as.data.table(x)
#       index V1
#1: 2016-07-21  1
#2: 2016-07-22  2
#3: 2016-07-24  4
#4: 2016-07-25  5
#5: 2016-07-26  6
#6: 2016-07-27  7
#7: 2016-07-29  9
#8: 2016-07-30 10
#9: 2016-07-31 11
```

Comment: Thanks. This means `as.data.table.xts(x)` was removed in `1.9.7` and replaced by `as.data.table(x)`.

Comment: @user227710  It could be the case as I am also using the same version.